# OpenERP 7 development environment: web module not found

Tags: eclipse, odoo

I setup an Ubuntu environment and used bzr to get the 3 trunks: addons, server, web

Everything works and the server starts fine.

I then loaded the project in Eclipse and tried to run openerp-server. I got this error (module web: module not found). I then copied the entries (addons_path) in the openerp-server.conf from /etc/ to the conf file in server/install folder. I also created a copy of this file and pasted in server folder, in the hopes that eclipse would pick it up.

But I am still getting the same error. Three questions please:

1. Which conf file should I add this path for eclipse to use? Where does this file reside?
2. If I must use a command line switch to specify the web/addons path then how do I do that in eclipse?
3. There used to be a file with a lot of different variable such as pg_path, rpc, etc. Is that file still around? Maybe that is where I need to make this entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a "-c /etc/openerp-server.conf" argument. Right click on the openerp-server file, launch the properties window, select Run/Debug Settings, select the only launch configuration available, edit, select the arguments tab.

Answer (score 0):

I added them manually to eclipse run configurations > arguments.

e.g.

```
--db_host = {host}
--db_port = {port}
--db_user = {user}
--db_password = {password}
--addons = ../addons,../server/addons
```